# how to call a REST API for Actions on Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google

I have seen some answers and still a little confused about how to call an REST API for Actions on google assistant.

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

// Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library.
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');

// Import the firebase-functions package for deployment.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const http  = require('https');


// Instantiate the Dialogflow client.
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'favorite color'.
// The intent collects a parameter named 'color'.
app.intent('favorite color', (conv, {any}) => {
    //const luckyNumber = any.length;
    // Respond with the user's lucky number and end the conversation.
    //conv.close('Your lucky number is ' + luckyNumber);
    return callApi(any).then((output) => {
    console.log(output);
    conv.close(`I found ${output.length} items!!`);
    }).catch(() => {
        conv.close('Error occurred while trying to get vehicles. Please try again later.');
    });
});

function callApi (any){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Create the path for the HTTP request to get the vehicle

        //Make the HTTP request to get the vehicle
        http.get({host: 'hawking.sv.cmu.edu', port: 9023, path: '/dataset/temporary'}, (res) => {
            let body = ''; // var to store the response chunks
            res.on('data', (d) => { body += d; }); // store each response chunk
            res.on('end', () => {
                // After all the data has been received parse the JSON for desired data
                let response = JSON.parse(body);
                let output = {};
            //
            //     //copy required response attributes to output here
            //
                console.log(response.length.toString());
                resolve(output);
                // callback(output);
            });
            res.on('error', (error) => {
                console.log(`Error calling the API: ${error}`)
                reject();
            });
        }); //http.get

        // let output = {};
        // resolve(output);
    });     //promise
}

// Set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request.
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

It always shows that:

MalformedResponse
'final_response' must be set.

It seems that http.get is asynchronous and before it made an http request, it already return the result without waiting for finishing the request.

I have add 'return' in app.intent functions but still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the free tier of Firebase? On the free tier, outbound URL connections are disabled: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: no...I am using the paid one... I don't know why I cannot hit an url on app.intent... today I tried another method.

Comment: Are you logging the result of your promise to see if it is getting called correctly? Maybe there's an error in your logic that is crashing the webhook code.

Answer (score -1):

```
app.intent('demo14mata', (conv, {any}) => {
    var html = ""
    http.get(url,(res)=>{

        res.on("data",(data)=>{
            html+=data
        })

        res.on("end",()=>{
            console.log(html)
            conv.close('return info is' + html);
        })
    }).on("error",(e)=>{
        console.log('something wrong')
        conv.close('no info return');
    })
    conv.close('no info return is(outside)' + html);
});
```

Comment: I try this today, it shows that in simulator: no info return is(outside)

Comment: if I create a nodejs file and run the same code in my machine, everything is ok.  I am sure no problems with url